# Accessing every other component with React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to set the background of every other  component in my project. I've tried multiple ways to do this, as you would if it was plain HTML and CSS.

(Note: 'card-container' is the class name of the div inside the < Card /> component)

React (.jsx) code:

```
<div className="cards">
    <Card />
    <Card />
    <Card />
    <Card />
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.cards .card-container:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Whatever I seem to try either makes every < Card /> element's background red, or just the first < Card /> instance.

Any tips are much appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

Rendered HTML below:

```
<div id="root">
    <div style="margin: 10px;">
        <div class="cards">
            <div class="card-container">...</div>
            <div class="card-container">...</div>
            <div class="card-container">...</div>
            <div class="card-container">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the rendered HTML?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink added the rendered HTML

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mccarthy-1gonv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's so interesting. We have the same code yet only my first Card component gets the red background...

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it should be working.

1. Check if anything else is not actually overwriting the css (`!important`).
2. Open developer tools and inspect/tinker with styling real time.
3. Verify the selectors/children Card's classes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the card component take class name as props and pass a class in every other element to do that.

```
className={`root `,${props.className}}
```